# Firebase init Provider Class Not Found Exception

Tags: java, android, firebase

I get the following error when I try to run my app on a Android version 4.4.4. However this application works without any problem in the Android 5 and above versions.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider 
com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find 
class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: /data/app/
```

The min SDK version is 16. 
I have tried to make this work by adding

```
multiDexEnabled true
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

And it did not work.

Secondly I also tried to achieve success via the following .txt file which didn't work either.

Multidex-config.txt

```
com/google/firebase/provider/FirebaseInitProvider.class
```

Comment: Have you add FirebaseInitProvider as Primary Dex in buidType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with `multidex:1.0.3` you must also call this (extending the Application class):

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?){
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        MultiDex.install(base);
    }
}
```